# Insert mode in curses.textpad in python

Tags: python, ncurses

While doing this in python:

```
tp = curses.textpad.Textbox(stdscr, insert_mode=True)
text = tp.edit()
```

I get

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Could you please tell me how to enable insert mode in curses.textpad? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch in http://bugs.python.org/issue13051 solves the issue. Thanks to Narendra Sisodiya :)